energy band structure of a semiconductor
I need to create an  energy band structure of a semiconductor plot diagram or of  One-dimensional crystal with periodic potential, where only several lattice
points are included through tikzpicture. I tried this formula but Latex gave me error :
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Set up styles
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=8em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

    % Draw the bands and the band gap
    \node [block, fill=blue!20] (conduction) at (0, 3) {Conduction Band};
    \node [block, fill=white, minimum height=2em, text centered] (bandgap) at (0, 1.5) {Band Gap};
    \node [block, fill=red!20] (valence) at (0, 0) {Valence Band};

    % Labels
    \node at (-3, 3) {Energy};
    \node at (0, -1) {Position};

    % Draw arrows
    \draw [line] (conduction) -- (bandgap);
    \draw [line] (bandgap) -- (valence);

    % Add vertical energy axis
    \draw[->] (-3, -1) -- (-3, 4);
    
    % Add horizontal position axis
    \draw[->] (-3, -1) -- (3, -1);

    % Draw horizontal lines for conduction and valence bands
    \draw[dashed] (-3, 3) -- (conduction);
    \draw[dashed] (-3, 0) -- (valence);
\end{tikzpicture}

Thanks in advance.

Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Unrelated to your question, but please note that \tikzstyle is obsolete. Have a look at \tikzset instead.

Using latex' arrows appears to require the arrows TikZ library (\usetikzlibrary{arrows}); with that addition, your example works.

Below is redwriten your code fragment in form of MWE (Minimal Working Example), which you can test as it is. It gives the same result as your code fragment, but code is a bit shorter.
\documentclass[margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[% Set up styles
node distance = 11mm,
  start chain = A going below,
   arr/.style = {-Latex},
box/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, rounded corners, fill=#1, 
                          text width=8em, align=center, minimum height=#2,
                          on chain=A, join=by arr},
                        ]
% Draw the bands and the band gap
\node[box=blue!20/4em]  {Conduction Band};
\node[box=white/2em]    {Band Gap};
\node[box=red!20/4em]   {Valence Band};

% Add axis with label
\coordinate[below left=of A-3.south west] (aux);
\draw[arr] (aux) to ["Energy", sloped]  ++ (0, 7);
\draw[arr] (aux) to ["Position" ']      ++ (5, 0);

% Draw horizontal lines for conduction and valence bands
\draw[dashed] (A-1.west) -- ++ (-1,0);
\draw[dashed] (A-3.west) -- ++ (-1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


